# Challenging Probability Theory

Tags: probability

ENG

How to calculate the probability that any event will occur at least once for a given number of attempts, and also taking into account the fact that the probability of an event increases with each attempt in an algebraic or geometric progression?

In simple words, the probability of any event x, it will increase by Δx with each attempt, for example: the probability that my grandmother will give me a pie today is 0.2, tomorrow - 0.4, and so on, until the guaranteed pie on the fifth day. how do I calculate the probability that I will get a pie at least once in 3 days?
P.s. Sorry for my english

RUS
Как рассчитать вероятность того, что хотя-бы один раз произойдет какое либо событие за данное количества попыток, а также с учетом того факта, что вероятность события увеличивается с каждой попыткой в алгебраической или геометрической прогрессии?

Простыми словами вероятность какого либо события х, она увеличится на Δх с каждой попыткой например: вероятность того, что бабушка даст мне пирожок сегодня - 0.2, завтра - 0.4 и так далее, до гарантированного пирожка на пятый день. как вычислить вероятность того, что я получу пирожок хотя бы один раз за 3 дня?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: i did it, thanks.

Comment: Hi, maybe put the english text first? People may skip over the question without looking otherwise

Comment: Thanks for the advice,  Just i'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

If the probability of success on day $n$ is $p_n$, then the probability of at least one success in the first $m$ days is $1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)\times\cdots\times(1-p_m)$ (provided each $p_n\le1$).

Comment: Thanks, you realy help me.

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" my answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it.